# Download pushed file using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Probably, the question sounds like already answered and googleable, but I didn't manage to find an answer.

I have an WebApi installed as windows service with SignalR support. After some operations, I try to push *.zip file to clients:

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
   zip.AddDirectory(mydir);
   Clients.All.pushFile(zip,"application/zip, application/octet-stream",myname);
}
```

I have several clients: C# WinForms app and HTML page with JavaScript.
I tried to handle this method using [FileSaver.js](http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/), but it seems, that it does not support zip or I've been doing something wrong:

```
pushFile: function (result, type, name) {
            try {
                var blob = new Blob(result, type);
                saveAs(blob, name);
            } catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
```

So the question - how to handle my SignalR file push with JavaScript client? I would like to have an save file dialog.
If this question is already answered, please, share the link and accept my apologies for duplicate! Thank you!

Comment: the `pushFile` gets called in js? can you check in Firebug what it receives?

Comment: Yes, it does. I receive an Object.
http://prntscr.com/257lhv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not help, but hope it can give you some idea of how to solve your problem.

```
    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        var mStream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] fileData = ;//get file data here
        string fileName = ; // get file name here
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileData);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        zip.AddEntry(fileName, memoryStream);
        mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        zip.AddDirectory(mydir);
        zip.Save(mStream);
        mStream.Position = 0;

         Clients.All.pushFile(mStream,"application/zip, application/octet-stream");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Writing file to stream and passing it to FileSaver did the trick, now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround until you find out why the filesaver.js is not working:
I believe you use this ZipFile: http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/8b981f77-742a-5f47-6299-c27104871d8c.htm

In C#:

```
     //SignalR
         string zipName = "myZip"
         Clients.All.pushFileNotification("Download.aspx?myZip=" + zipName);

     //Download.aspx
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request["myZip"]))
        {
            download(Request["myZip"]);
        }
     }

    private void download(string myZip)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        if (myZip == "myZip") // some validation if you want
        {                
            using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    zip.AddDirectory(mydir);
                    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        Response.ClearHeaders();
                        Response.ClearContent();
                        zip.Save(output);
                        byte[] buffer = output.ToArray();
                        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString());
                        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myZip);


                        if (buffer.Length < 1)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                        {
                            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Response.End();
    }
```

In html add an iframe:

```
<iframe id="zipLoader" src="#" width="0" height="0" tabindex="-1" title="empty" hidden style="display: none;">
</iframe>
```

and in js:

```
pushFileNotification: function (result) {
        try {
             $('#zipLoader').attr('src', result);
        } catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
```

It is ugly but it should work. The best would be if it would work like you wrote it.
I use jQuery, but you can understand what happens here and you can replace it to plain js.

Comment: My zip file does not have any Path on server, it's created dynamically.

Comment: even so, there is a method that writes it to the response

Comment: Could you give a hint, or better - an example for my case? How to write file to response?